# Simple jquery image editor with text function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I'm looking for an image editor in js/jquery with possibility for user to add text other the image, move it, choose color.
Crop and rotate function for image.

Is there something like that? I found only one in codecanyon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look a this open source javascript Image Editor :

[tui.image-editor](https://github.com/nhnent/tui.image-editor)

> #### Feature
>
> - Load image to canvas
> - Undo/Redo (With shortcut)
> - Crop
> - Flip
> - Rotation
> - Free Drawing
> - Line drawing
> - Shape
> - Icon
> - Text
> - Mask Filter
> - Image Filter

[Basic demo page](http://ui.toast.com/tui-image-editor/)